# How to display div dynamically on window

Tags: jquery

When i click on any point of screen i need to display a div on clicked point how to do this. explain me with example

Comment: You mean like a tooltip?

Comment: Google for ["jQuery tooltip plugin"](http://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=jquery+tooltip+plugin) - you'll find a lot of results, including [comparisons of 30 libraries](http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/).

Comment: Maybe show us what have you tried and how it doesnt work

Comment: The answer you accepted won't work in IE.

Comment: Thanks for intimation its not working in ie7. i change my selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/patrick_dw/erG9Q/

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    $( "<div class='mydiv'></div>" ).offset({top:e.pageY,left:e.pageX} )
                                    .appendTo(document.body);
});
```

*css*

```
div.mydiv {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    background: orange;
}
```

- Assign [a `.click()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/click/) to the `document`
- In the handler, [create a new element](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) `$( "<div class='mydiv'></div>" )`
- Set its [page `.offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to the point of the click `.offset({top:e.pageY,left:e.pageX} )`
- [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)  the page `.appendTo(document.body)`

Answer (score 0):

Use clientX and clientY to get the mouse position. This is a simple example:

```
$(window).click(function(e)
{
    var div = $("<div style='position: absolute; width: 10px; height: 10px; background: red;'>hello</div>");
    div.css('top', e.clientY);
    div.css('left', e.clientX);

    div.appendTo("body");
});
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6nEN7/).